# Writing Macro in ImageJ to open all files from folder, change B/C, subtract background, assign a threshold

Tags: macros, imagej

I'm trying to write a macro that:

1. Opens up all .tif images from a folder
2. Converts them all to 32-bit images
3. Adjusts the brightness and contrast to a certain min/max (130/160)
4. Subtracts the background with a rolling ball radius of 15 and light background checked
5. Adjusts the threshold to a specific min/max values

I have no experience with code and have more than 600 images to go through. Manually would take weeks. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please use the ImageJ macro recorder to get the main code steps (2. to 5.) for the desired operations. Then surround these code steps by the macro code available from:
"Help >> Examples >> Macro >> Process Folder"